$ ap+bq=1$ iff $a^2p+b^2q=1 $
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity 1 then for $ a,b \in R$ there exist $ p,q \in R$ such that
$ ap+bq=1 $ implies $a^2p'+b^2q'=1 $  there exist $p', q' \in R$
It obviously holds in $ \mathbb{Z}$ So i tried to find by calculating co-prime numbers but did not find any algorithm for finding $p, q$ for $a^2$ and $b^2$
So any hint for general commutative ring?
Converse part is easy to show.
I don't know how this result "$(a,b)=1$ implies $ (a^2,b^2)=1$" will help me.
Do existence of such $p,q$ in a arbitrary Commutative ring implies coprime in arbitrary Commutative ring.

Can you clean up the first sentence? Furthermore, not that it currently isn't an iff statement per your title.

If you have trouble writing in English try https://translate.google.com or a similar service.

This question is similar to: Show that if $(a,b)=(1)$, then $(a^2,b^2)=(1)$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The title to your question is making a false statement; you need primes on the second $p$ and $q$ (and you need a "there exists" in there somewhere, too).
